# 'ref' not working like I think it should

Tags: c#, .net, pass-by-reference, value-type

I have the following code which when looking at it while it's running shows that the initial 'myInt' and 'myFloat' do not change their values until the method call returns back.  Shouldn't their values change each time they are altered within the called methods since they are passed as 'ref' each time?

```
class Tester
{
    public void Run()
    {
        int myInt = 42;
        float myFloat = 9.685f;
        Console.WriteLine("Before starting: \n value of myInt: {0} \n value of myFloat: {1}", myInt, myFloat);
        // pass the variables by reference
        Multiply( ref myInt, ref myFloat );
        Console.WriteLine("After finishing: \n value of myInt: {0} \n value of myFloat: {1}", myInt, myFloat);
     }
     private static void Multiply (ref int theInt, ref float theFloat)
     {
        theInt = theInt * 2;
        theFloat = theFloat *2;
        Divide( ref theInt, ref theFloat);
     }
     private static void Divide (ref int theInt, ref float theFloat)
     {
        theInt = theInt / 3;
        theFloat = theFloat / 3;
        Add(ref theInt, ref theFloat);
     }
     public static void Add(ref int theInt, ref float theFloat)
     {
        theInt = theInt + theInt;
        theFloat = theFloat + theFloat;
     }
     static void Main()
     {
        Tester t = new Tester();
        t.Run();
     }
}
```

Comment: Are you looking at their values in the debugger? What values are you observing? Which method call specifically?

Comment: I can't seem to find the relevant SO question, but I am pretty sure that this situation (passing values by ref, where the local scope variable has the same name as the ref parameter) confuses the debugger and it may not show you the correct value. It has no effect on the code execution, just on real-time inspection while debugging.

Comment: and only on the graphical debugger - the command line should return the correct value for `this.myInt`.

Comment: @sixlettervariables  Yes, I'm looking in the debugger by adding them to my Watch list.  As soon as it goes into the first called method they sort of blur/gray out, but their values (and their grayed/blurred status) do not change until the call stack returns to the Run() method.

Comment: Also if you are backing up the call stack to look at the value from the command line, it's not going to be current either, because you've gone back in time when you do that. As @Fernaref this would only affect using the GUI to inspect outside the active procedure, while at the current breakpoint.

Comment: @Gijera: if they are blurred you must click the refresh button to view their current values. The same would be true if you watched a method call.

Comment: @Gijera: Have a look at my answer now... I think I've worked out what's going on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: Okay, having seen the description in your comments...

If you put a breakpoint in (say) `Add` then your watch variables won't change unless you get them to be re-evaluated - which has to be done in the right stack from. When the breakpoint has been hit, go to the Call Stack view, double click on the "Run" method (which doesn't change where you've got to, just which stack frame you're looking at) and you'll see the values update.

Comment: I think he means the `myInt` and `myFloat` in the main scope, in the `Run` method - rather than the parameter variables within the other methods.  I.e. using the debugger to check those variables, they don't change until the `Multiply` call completes (OP: " the *initial* 'myInt' and 'myFloat' do not change their values until the method call returns back.")

Comment: @Kieren: They should do. If you put a break-point within `Add`, you *should* see the values having changed. If you don't, that's just a debugger anomaly.

Comment: I reckon the answer is, 'it's a debugger anomaly' then :)  I'll go with that -

Comment: @Kieren: Yup, thanks for pointing out the meaning of the question. I've edited my answer already, and will try it in VS 2010.

Comment: I'd say that myInt and myFloat is out of scope and hence doesn't actually have a value. Sure the memory location they point to in some other scope has a value or maybe even several values in several scopes but in the scope of multiply they don't exist

Comment: @Rune: The watch window could capture the right scope, of course... and as soon as you double-click on the right line in the call stack, it works fine.

Comment: @sixlettervariables: But changing the scope by double-clicking on the right stack frame in the Call Stack window *doesn't* cause an error - it shows the updated values.

Comment: @Jon: I don't remember which version of your answer I was comment on, I've removed the comment.

Answer (score 1):

It's a debugger anomaly, the values change right away, as per Jon's and jamietre's comments.

Comment: That may be, but the strange thing is, is that the book I'm using, has the following question in regards to this example/exercise:"Stop debugging, run the program again, and when it reaches the breakpoint in Run(), set a watch on 'myInt'.  Step through the methods.  When does the value of 'myInt' change?"  Then it answers this question in the appendix as:  "The value of myInt doesn't change until control returns to Run(), after Multiply() method has finished.

Comment: It probably means a different  `myInt`: the `myInt` that's a parameter in the other methods called, not the main one!

Comment: Does the same thing whether I 'Watch' the parameter or the 'main one'

Comment: ...sounds like a debugger anomaly to me!

Comment: @Gijera: Which book is this? It's incorrect - the value of `myInt` really *does* change immediately. I'd be very suspicious of the book, which appears to be using a debugger anomaly as justification for an incorrect conclusion.

Comment: @Jon Skeet:  It is called "Learning C# 3.0" by O'Reilly

Comment: @Gijera: Hmmm... I noticed a certain amount of sloppiness when I reviewed Programming C# 3.0. Looks like this is another instance of that. Double-click on the right stack frame in the call stack and you'll see that the variable values really *have* been updated...

Comment: @Jon Skeet:  Just to note, my main book for C# is "Programming C# 4.0" by O'Reilly, and am only going through the exercises in the aforementioned book in order to pass my class.  This 'main' book, I find, is written quite well, at least for my current level of comprehension.

Comment: @Gijera: I *have* Programming C# 4.0, but I haven't read it yet :) I think Ian Griffiths did the bulk of the work, and I trust him :)

Answer (score 1):

You placed a Watch on the expressions `myInt` and `myFloat` rather than the expressions `theInt` and `theFloat`, thus you no longer see their values. `myInt` and `myFloat` do not exist in the *current scope*.

[image: The Watch Window uses expressions not variables]

You can back up in the call stack to observe their values, or place a watch on all four of the **expressions** you care about.

[image: Select the original method in your call stack to view their values]

Comment: I've tried refreshing and all I get is "myInt The name 'myInt' does not exist in the current context".  Also, why does the scope matter?  Shouldn't they be allocated on the heap (though I may not understand the heap fully, so yea...) and therefore can be accessed from anywhere?  Lastly, what do you mean by 'ask for re-evaluation'?

Comment: I've updated my pictures to reflect what is actually happening. I'd meant to click the refresh to show the problem, but I realized that wasn't helpful :) Scope matters because the Watch Window is looking at an *expression*. The *expression* `myInt` does not exist in `Add()` or `Multiply()` but `theInt` does exist! You've run into the issue where you believe you've asked the Debugger to watch a specific variable in a specific scope, but rather you've asked for a given expression to be evaluated at each step.

Comment: Highlight something like `theInt * 2`, Right Click and goto *Add Watch*. As you step through each method you'll understand better what the Watch Window provides.

Comment: Is there any debug tool that would do what I want?  Instead of looking at an expression, have it look at just the value of an object in memory?

Comment: Yes and no. Yes the heap is available anywhere. No `myInt` and `myFloat` are not on "the heap", `t` is though. No that doesn't mean you can just Watch the expression `t` and *see* it everywhere. You shouldn't care terribly about heap vs stack allocation in *most* .Net applications. A full explanation of the .Net memory model is a bit more than this comment box can handle. Search for ["stack heap .net"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=stack+heap+.net) for some questions.